# How many times did Mom and the Professor actually date?

Tags: tv, futurama

In several episodes you get a rehashing of Dr. Farnsworth and Mom's relationship but it always seems to start in different ways.  How many times did they actually date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They appear to have dated on [4 separate occasions](http://theinfosphere.org/Farnsworth-Mom_relationship) (dates taken from [this timeline](http://theinfosphere.org/Timeline)):

- 2881: Dr. Farnsworth designs [Q. T. McWhiskers](http://theinfosphere.org/Q._T._McWhiskers) for [Mom's Friendly Robot Company](http://theinfosphere.org/MomCorp), but then breaks up with Mom after she suggests making it into a giant weapon. (episode: ["Mother's Day"](http://theinfosphere.org/Mother%27s_Day))
- 2927: Dr. Farnsworth designs the fuel-inefficient [sport-utility robot](http://theinfosphere.org/Sport-Utility_Robot), from which is derived all future robot designs, leading to global warming. In 2931 he breaks up with Mom again and leaves the company. (episode: ["Crimes of the Hot"](http://theinfosphere.org/Crimes_of_the_Hot))
- 2970: Dr. Farnsworth returns to the company and discovers dark matter. It is at this time that he fathers [Igner](http://theinfosphere.org/Igner), but Mom leaves him for her ex-husband. (movie: [*Bender's Game*](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Game))
- 3001: The two get back together briefly for some "hot, dry sex". (episode: ["Mother's Day"](http://theinfosphere.org/Mother%27s_Day))

Comment: "Nothing in here except for a couple of elephant skin rugs."